AR js studio project (image marker) working on glitch, but I want this to work without internet on my desktop
I'm encountering difficulties loading assets locally on my desktop without an internet connection. I've correctly placed them in the designated folder, but they are not rendering as expected.
I'm using [AR js studio] and attempting to load [video] using [pattern].
I've reviewed the console logs for any relevant error messages but haven't found any. I've also tried opening the assets directly in a web browser, and they display correctly.
Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>AR Video Marker</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  <script>   

    AFRAME.registerComponent('videohandler', {
      init()   
 {
        const marker = this.el;
        const video = document.querySelector('#vid');

        marker.addEventListener('markerFound', () => {
          video.play();
        });

        marker.addEventListener('markerLost', () => {
          video.pause();
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
  <a-scene vr-mode-ui="false" loading-screen="false" arjs="sourceType: webcam">
    <a-assets>
      <video id="vid" src="path/to/your/video.mp4" preload="auto" loop crossorigin playsinline autoplay></video>
    </a-assets>
    <a-marker type="pattern" preset="custom" url="path/to/your/marker.patt" videohandler smooth>
      <a-video src="#vid" scale="1.9 2.5 0" position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-video>
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>

